# python datetime extract hour minute fast

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 878000*1 dataframe, where the 1 column is date in several years. I have the following code to create new columns and store year,month,day,hour,min,week in different new columns:

```
for i in train.index:
    train['Year'][i] = train.Dates[i].year
    train['Month'][i] = train.Dates[i].month
    train['Day'][i] = train.Dates[i].day
    train['Hour'][i] = train.Dates[i].hour
    train['Min'][i] = train.Dates[i].minute
    train['Week'][i] = train.Dates[i].isocalendar()[1]
```

However this is really slow, my computer has been working overnight for this simple command and it still not finished. I am wondering if there is some faster way that I can use to extract these information without waiting for so long?

Comment: Any reason you want those as columns as you can just access those via the `.dt` access of the index as needed - seems a bit of a waste to store them unless it's necessary - but something like: `train['Year'] = train.index.dt.year` etc... should be fairly quick

Comment: I am creating engineering features for machine learning usage, which requires different features in new columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you don't want to do it in loop, you should work with vectorized data:

```
train['Year'] = train.Dates.dt.year
train['Month'] = train.Dates.dt.month
```

...

Comment: `train['Week'] = train.Dates.dt.weekofyear` replaces `train['Week'][i] = train.Dates[i].isocalendar()[1]`

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
In [15]: train = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2015-12-31', '2016-12-31'), columns=['Dates'])

In [16]: train.head()
Out[16]:
       Dates
0 2015-12-31
1 2016-01-01
2 2016-01-02
3 2016-01-03
4 2016-01-04
```

#### Solution

```
In [17]: fields = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Min', 'Week']

In [18]: f = lambda x: pd.Series([x[0].year, x[0].month,
                                  x[0].day, x[0].hour,
                                  x[0].minute, x[0].isocalendar()[1]],
                                 index=fields)


In [19]: train.apply(f, axis=1)
```

#### Looks like

```
Out[19]:
     Year  Month  Day  Hour  Min  Week
0    2015     12   31     0    0    53
1    2016      1    1     0    0    53
2    2016      1    2     0    0    53
3    2016      1    3     0    0    53
4    2016      1    4     0    0     1
5    2016      1    5     0    0     1
6    2016      1    6     0    0     1
7    2016      1    7     0    0     1
8    2016      1    8     0    0     1
9    2016      1    9     0    0     1
10   2016      1   10     0    0     1
11   2016      1   11     0    0     2
12   2016      1   12     0    0     2
13   2016      1   13     0    0     2
14   2016      1   14     0    0     2
15   2016      1   15     0    0     2
16   2016      1   16     0    0     2
17   2016      1   17     0    0     2
18   2016      1   18     0    0     3
19   2016      1   19     0    0     3
20   2016      1   20     0    0     3
21   2016      1   21     0    0     3
22   2016      1   22     0    0     3
23   2016      1   23     0    0     3
24   2016      1   24     0    0     3
25   2016      1   25     0    0     4
26   2016      1   26     0    0     4
27   2016      1   27     0    0     4
28   2016      1   28     0    0     4
29   2016      1   29     0    0     4
..    ...    ...  ...   ...  ...   ...
337  2016     12    2     0    0    48
338  2016     12    3     0    0    48
339  2016     12    4     0    0    48
340  2016     12    5     0    0    49
341  2016     12    6     0    0    49
342  2016     12    7     0    0    49
343  2016     12    8     0    0    49
344  2016     12    9     0    0    49
345  2016     12   10     0    0    49
346  2016     12   11     0    0    49
347  2016     12   12     0    0    50
348  2016     12   13     0    0    50
349  2016     12   14     0    0    50
350  2016     12   15     0    0    50
351  2016     12   16     0    0    50
352  2016     12   17     0    0    50
353  2016     12   18     0    0    50
354  2016     12   19     0    0    51
355  2016     12   20     0    0    51
356  2016     12   21     0    0    51
357  2016     12   22     0    0    51
358  2016     12   23     0    0    51
359  2016     12   24     0    0    51
360  2016     12   25     0    0    51
361  2016     12   26     0    0    52
362  2016     12   27     0    0    52
363  2016     12   28     0    0    52
364  2016     12   29     0    0    52
365  2016     12   30     0    0    52
366  2016     12   31     0    0    52
```